# reference for time-inhomogeneous random walk

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, random-walk, time-series

I have a problem with a Markov chain that is time-inhomogeneous.
Consider a Markov chain $(X_t)$ in discrete time $t=0, 1, \dotsc$ on the integers. At each time $t$, the process can go up by 1, down by 1 or stay constant, but these probabilities depend on time $t$. Formally,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}[X_{t+1}=X_t+1|X_t]=p_t;\\
\mathbb{P}[X_{t+1}=X_t-1|X_t]=q_t;\\
\mathbb{P}[X_{t+1}=X_t|X_t]=1-p_t- q_t.
\end{align*}

I am interested in the recurrence properties of the processes $(X_t)_t$ and how they relate to the probabilities $(p_t, q_t)_t$.
Unfortunately, I did not find a good, accessible reference. Most textbooks focus on time-homogeneous Markov chains only.

Does anybody have a suggestion for a good reference?

Comment: The following link (https://arxiv.org/abs/2212.01722) seems to answer your question in a slightly more general setting (also allowing the transition probabilities to be space-inhomogeneous).